# Retrieving Incorrect Table Coordinates

Tags: javascript, html

I created a checkers board using tables. I want to retrieve the x and y coordinates of a cell. However, the `this.parentNode.rowIndex` keeps giving me -1. I've spent countless hours looking for the error. Can anyone find it for me?

```
var board = [[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
         [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1],
         [-1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0],
         [0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1]];

var gray = -1; //distinguishing players
var red = 1;

function makeBoard() {
//create a table
var tbl = document.createElement("table");
//create a <tr> for each row
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");

    //create a <td> for each column
    for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        var td = document.createElement("td");
        //setting the attributes of a square
        td.setAttribute("width", "50");
        td.setAttribute("height", "50");
        if ((i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 != 0) || (i % 2 !=0 && j % 2 == 0)) {
            td.style.backgroundColor = "black";
        }
        else if (board[i][j] == red) {
            td.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
        else if (board[i][j] == gray) {
            td.style.backgroundColor = "gray";
        }
        td.onclick = function() {
            alert(this.cellIndex + ", " + this.parentNode.rowIndex); //RETRIEVING WRONG COORDINATES
        }
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    tbl.appendChild(tr);
}
tbl.setAttribute("border", "10");
return tbl;
}
```

If you feel that something is missing, please let me know.

Comment: tried a jsfiddle, works in Firefox, fails in Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/nBbd2/1/

Comment: Try creating a `<tbody>` element and placing the row elements in that. You could also create a JSFiddle demo for us to debug a live thing.

Comment: @IanKuca [You appear to be correct](http://jsfiddle.net/emosaurusrex/nBbd2/24/), sir.

Comment: Adding the `tr` elements to a `tbody` seems to fix the chrome issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

`sectionRowIndex` instead of just `index`..

Seems to be working fine in both chrome and Firefox

```
this.parentNode.sectionRowIndex
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/vsBpC/6/)**

Answer (score 1):

The missing tbody doesn't really seem to be the problem in this case. Looks like this is related to the way rows and cells are being added.

Instead of using appendChild you should use table.insertRow and row.insertCell methods

So when adding a row, instead of

```
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
```

Use

```
var tr = tbl.insertRow(0);
```

Same applied for the cells, use

```
var td = tr.insertCell(j);
```

Also remove both appendChild calls for tr and td at the end of your blocks

Working fix here http://jsfiddle.net/nBbd2/30/